# Select last option in drop menu or count number of options in drop menu for ui vision rpa kantu selenium katalon recorder

Tags: javascript, selenium, xpath, rpa, katalon-recorder

I have this drop menu

```
        <select name='sidebar-2_position'>
        <option value=''>&mdash; Seleziona &mdash;</option>
        <option value='1'> 1 </option>
        <option value='2'> 2 </option>
        <option value='3'> 3 </option>
        <option value='4'> 4 </option>
        <option value='5' selected='selected'> 5 </option>
        <option value='6'> 6 </option>
        </select>
```

I need to select last item (in my case 6) in a drop-down menu but I don't know the number of items in the drop menu because change always.

I'm interested to know what kind of xpath I can use for this feature.

I use ui vision rpa kantu which is based on selenium xpaths.

I can select the first element using this xpath (index=1, index=2, index=3)

```
    {
      "Command": "select",
      "Target": "xpath=//select[@name='sidebar-2_position']",
      "Value": "index=1"
    }
```

How do I select the last item in the drop-down menu unknowing the number of items in drop menu?

If I could know the number of items on the drop-down menu, I could solve my problem.

I need to solve this:

-) xpath that select last option unknowing number of options

or

2. javascript to have the number of element in my drop menu and after detect it via index=N

Comment: `document.getElementById("yourSelectId").length` should give you the number of options

Comment: I have id but i have name <select name='sidebar-2_position'> can I use your javascript with name and not id ?

Comment: If there aren't any other elements with the same name, `getElementsByName('sidebar-2_position')[0]` should work. Or if you only have one select in you page you could use `querySelector('select')`

Comment: On ui vision rpa with executesctipt show "Error in executeScript_Sandbox code: document.getElementByName is not a function" I think require a return command to get value from javascript

Comment: there is an s...it's Elements, not Element

Comment: This command seems wrong, nothing works

Comment: it works fine with both options here: https://jsfiddle.net/Lahspzm3/4/

Comment: I tried in ui vision and seems not working ui.vision/rpa/docs/selenium-ide/executescript provide the code macro please

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I'm 100% clear on what you're asking, but try this to find the last `<option>` node without having to know how many there are:

```
const targets = document.evaluate('//select//option[last()]/@value', document, null, XPathResult.ORDERED_NODE_SNAPSHOT_TYPE, null);
console.log(targets.snapshotItem(0).value)
```

Output:

```
"6"
```

Comment: I tried it in ui vision ui.vision/rpa/docs/selenium-ide/executescript and show error, how i can use your code ? i need only xpath not other command unsupported. thanks

Comment: @cicoria The xpath is in the answer: `//select//option[last()]/@value`.

Comment: Your reply report a wrong xpath command, it seems not a selenium xpath this. Try it in katalon recorder and show the log please another problem in your command is missed the xpath to detect correct select. <select name='sidebar-2_position'>